# How do I export ALL calendars in Mozilla lightning

Tags: macos, thunderbird, lightning

I have seen singular versions of this but I was wondering if I could easily export ALL calendars into one file. I have about 20-30 calendars...

Thunderbird 17.0.2 
Ligntning 1.9
Mac OS X SL